# error when use segue after click button in viewController

Tags: swift

Hi I have tableViewController , that contain tableview Cell , in tableViewCell I have another tableViewController and tableViewCell that every cell have one textField and button , when I click on button(in second tableview) I send data to server and its work good , and if I click back button its work correct , but if I first click on button(in second tableview) and then click on backbtn  my application crash , I don't know why , please Help me

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableview.delegate = self
    tableview.datasource = self

    backbtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(backbtn), for: .touchUpInside)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(notification1), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "notification1"), object: nil)
}

@objc func backbtn(){
   performSegue(withIdentifier: backToMain, sender: self)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return Request.count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let height = childnumber * 40

    return CGFloat(unselectedCellHeight+height+150)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "test") as? RequestCategoryTableVC{

        var category : Requst?

        category = FilteringRequest[indexPath.row]

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    cell.updateCell(categoryList: category!)
        }
    }

    return category()
}
```

second tableview

```
func updateCell(categoryList : Requst) {
    categoryTableRequestchild.dataSource = self
    categoryTableRequestchild.delegate = self
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

      return list.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    return category2()
    return Tabaecategory()
}
```

Comment: How does it crash? Please show us the output.

Comment: If it crahses, there should be an error message in console. It's an important piece of information in debugging. Please be aware of it, if you don't understand it, copy/paste here, but that's clearly a good hint for us to help or you.

Comment: Thread 1: signal SIGABRT , is my Error , if I don't click on textfield and just click on button in secondtableView I have no Error , but if I just click on textfield on secondtableView and then click on button I get this Error

Comment: What is category() and Tabaecategory() that you return from your cellForRowAt methods?

Comment: If you only get crashes if you interact with any of the textfields, it sounds like the crash is related to the textfields... How do you create them? Show us the code for the cell's containing the textfields, please.

Comment: @modi Check your outlets from your storyboard in the `Connections Inspector`.